# making a 3d python array from three 1d arrays

Tags: python, arrays

i am new in python and have a basic question:

I have three lists :

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 4, 5]
c = [5, 7, 8]
```

What i want is an array that looks something like :

```
x = np.array([1,2,5],[2,4,7],[5,7,8])
```

is there some on-line python trick to do this?

Comment: By 3d array, do you mean you want a 3x3 [matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics))?

Comment: Do you mean a 2D array?

Comment: "I have two numpy arrays in 1d" - Errr, no - you have *three* Python *lists* and you probably want a *2D* array :)

Comment: sorry for all the mistakes in defining the lists and arrays and stuff :-/  and thank you all for pointing out :) edited the question in correct format now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `zip(a, b, c)`, e.g, `x = np.array(*zip(a, b, c))` [Official Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: When the arrays are large, it is probably faster to use the pure numpy solution with `vstack` shown by Matti, instead of using the built-in `zip`.

Comment: @BasSwinckels +1 Not a numpy user, but from what I've heard I wouldn't doubt it :)

Comment: What can we do for matrix i have r,g,b matrixs I want to concatenate them to get a rgb matrix

Answer (score 5):

```
np.vstack((np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([1,2,3])))
```

or even simpler

```
np.vstack(([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another simple way is using `.T` which transposes the matrix.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 4, 5]
c = [5, 7, 8]

np.array([a,b,c]).T

array([[1, 2, 5],
       [2, 4, 7],
       [3, 5, 8]])
```

Comment: this is very elegant :) i figured out `np.array([a,b,c])`, but didn't know that we can use `.T` to find the transpose of it :) thank you for sharing the trick

Comment: Glad it helped! Numpy has some great little elegant tricks :)